# array to pointpairlist (ZedGraph)

Tags: c#, arrays, zedgraph

I'm trying to display some data using ZedGraph. The data was read in from a file, which is then stored in an array called heart_rate[x] which I'm trying to pass to the point pair list, however, it won't accept the string array. After searching, I assume it needs to be converted to double first. I've tried this but with no luck.

Here is the code that creates the array by reading data from a file. Ideally I don't want to change this, as I have other arrays written the same way, and this would require an entire program re-write.

```
                for (x = 0; x < hrm_data.Length; x = x + 6)
                {
                    heart_rate.Add(hrm_data[x]);
                }
```

Here is where I set up ZedGraph, obviously missing code to pass the array to the point pair list.

```
            GraphPane myPane = z_graph.GraphPane;
            myPane.Title = "HRM Data";
            myPane.XAxis.Title = "Time";
            myPane.YAxis.Title = "Readings";                
            PointPairList heart_rate_list = new PointPairList();                                             
            LineItem heart_rate_curve = myPane.AddCurve("Heart Rate", heart_rate_list, Color.Red, SymbolType.Diamond);                
            z_graph.AxisChange();
```

**EDIT**

Here is an example of the file I'm reading in. The first column of data is heart rate readings, Using the for loop I am only selecting the first column and adding that to the array

```
91 43 56 78 45 78
91 43 56 78 45 78
91 43 56 78 45 78
91 43 56 78 45 78
```

**EDIT 2**

Thankyou for all the help, I really appreciate it, however, I think I'm confusing everyone with what I'm asking for. This is a student project and I know some fellow students have done this that could help out.

Comment: Can you show an example of an item in `hrm_data`?

Comment: @Andreas Gustafsson its just plain text figures, so 80, 97, 43 etc. I know there's nothing wrong with the array itself as I've used it to display the data in a data table.

Comment: So each `hrm_data` item is a number stored as a `string`, and it should be plotted on the *Y* axis? And the `x` indices are the coordinates on the *X* axis?

Comment: @Andreas Gustafsson yes, the y-axis should display heart rate readings and the x-axis is the time

Comment: Hi, Where are you specifying the Y coordinates for the pointpair list . Every item in the pointpair list should contain X and Y coordinate. In your case I see only X .

Comment: @jaycyborg I haven't got to that part yet, I'm just trying to set the heart_rate array to the pointillist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply be able to take the string items of `hrm_data`, split them, pick the first item of the split and convert into `double`:s using the `Double.Parse` method.

Then use the `PointPairList(double[], double[])` constructor (see [here](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_PointPairList.htm)) to create your desired point pair list:

```
PointPairList heart_rate_list = new PointPairList(
    Enumerable.Range(0, hrm_data.Length).Select(i => (double)i).ToArray(),
    hrm_data.Select(item => Double.Parse(item.Split(' ')[0])). ToArray());
```

Note that the `x` coordinates are generated by creating an index collection which is cast to a `double` collection.

Comment: the hrm_data contains the whole file. The heart_rate[x] contains just the heart rate data. The data is split into 6 columns, hence the for loop above. So the loop only adds the first column to the heart_rate array.

Comment: OK, so what does one item of the `heart_rate` collection contain then?

Comment: I still don't follow? Do you mean that you *want* to select only the first column and discard the other columns? In that case, and if the `hrm_data` items are `string`:s, you could split each string item and take the first item of the split. I will update answer accordingly.

Comment: I think I'm confusing you and making it way harder than it should be sorry

Comment: @Calv Did you get to the bottom of your problem eventually? If my answer does not solve your problem, you should not accept it. It is better if you leave the question unanswered and instead add more information to your question.

Comment: sorry, I did eventually with the help of a fellow student. I accepted your answer because of the amount of effort you put into helping out. I now know not to next time

Answer (score 0):

yes as you have mentioned the code is incomplete .

```
  PointPairList heart_rate_list = new PointPairList();
```

since you have defined the list but you forgot you to set the parameters for it .Basically (x,y) ..thus you have to input all your array value as one of the parameters of x or y .Just make a loop to insert the value of array using foreach.
//taking  int x as time  for seconds add using

```
        foreach(int value in heart_rate) 
       {        y=value;
         heart_rate_list.Add(x,y)
        };
```

//now add it to the curve as you have done above